# Angular stopped working after deploy, problem with mat select and sending data

Tags: angular, angular7

I've done angular app everything is working on localhost but on a server(i wasn't doing deploy) some features don't. For instance, I've got (1) material select which is written in html and I can't open it on the remote desktop. Error:

```
ERROR TypeError: this._document.createElement is not a function
    at t._createHostElement (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at t.create (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at t._createOverlay (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at t._attachOverlay (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at t.ngOnChanges (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1
    at main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1
    at wa (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at qa (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at Object.updateDirectives (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
kn @ main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1
4main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateSize' of undefined
    at t.ngOnChanges (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1
    at main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1
    at wa (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at qa (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at Object.updateDirectives (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at Object.updateDirectives (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at ba (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at Ta (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at Pa (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
```

and I can't open date picker (2)
error :

```
RROR TypeError: O.throw is not a function
    at e.selector (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at e.error (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at e._error (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at e.error (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at e._error (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at e.error (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at e.notifyError (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at e._error (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at e.error (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.u (main.5a889a7e7ded1e8d0571.js:1)
```

1.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Select Role"  name="Role" ngModel required>
      <mat-option value="master">Master</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="driver">Driver</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="receptionist">Reception</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

2.

```
<input [min]="min" [max]="max" ngModel name="pickupTime" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt" type="text" [owlDateTime]="dt" required>
                <owl-date-time #dt></owl-date-time>
```

This is the package.json folder

```
{
  "name": "src-frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "github:angular/animations-builds",
    "@angular/cdk": "github:angular/cdk-builds",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "github:angular/material2-builds",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.0",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.27.2",
    "angularx-flatpickr": "^6.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "flatpickr": "^4.5.7",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^5.2.6",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

Form me it seems like it doesn't recognize mat select and date picker, is that maybe of some version difference? is that possible

Comment: Have you tested this locally? how did you deploy it?

Comment: we were doing deployment from this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=1250961)

Comment: on localhost, everything is working a specially I don't know why this input doesn't work

Comment: Where is material dependency? I'm talking about the link you've posted. I haven't found material over there. It's present in the content you've posted over here.

Comment: Well... in general, @angular/material guys write the nightly builds to run with the latest @angular version. Have you tried out angular 8...?

Comment: [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1250961/Deploying-an-Angular-Application-with-ASP-NET-Core)

Comment: so I will need to update my project to angular 8 and then try it?

Comment: Just a guess... because it happened in previous material releases. Give it a try.

Comment: I've noticed that you're also mixing angular dependencies versions (`"@angular/animations": "github:angular/animations-builds"`). Don't do it unless you have full knowledge of the inner behavior of angular.

Comment: doesn't work after updating and doing lots of thigs ;(

Comment: this first error screen occurs when I'm trying to click on select  ;(

Comment: Hi @PiotrKowalczyk, Did you find any solid solution? I am facing the same issue